# Formatting the time input field with html

Tags: html, forms

I have  a simple operating booking system using php. I give the user an option to select a data and time from date and time input fields. Now for the booking system I only want the user to be able to select in hour blocks but the current format of the time picker is hours:minutes:seconds in the format 00:00:00. Is there any way to disable the minutes and seconds? My current code is as follows, just the default for the time picker.

```
    <input type="time" name="time" id="time" />
```

Any help would be great if possible, I know its hard to format the date and time pickers and varies alot on web browser so i'm using google chrome latest version 48.0.2564.116. Thanks!

Comment: @HanletEscaño https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#time-state-(type=time)

Answer (score 2):

The HTML5 specification states that valid `type=time` `input` elements must have a [valid time string](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#valid-time-string) which must have:

> 1. Two ASCII digits, representing hour, in the range 0 ≤ hour ≤ 23
> 2. A ":" (U+003A) character
> 3. Two ASCII digits, representing minute, in the range 0 ≤ minute ≤ 59

The seconds themselves *are* already optional (that's part 4, but I didn't quote that above). However this does mean that the value of these elements wouldn't be valid without the minute entry.

Perhaps you'd be better off with a `type=number` `input` element instead, with a `min` of `0` and a `max` of `11` or `23` depending on your preference:

```html
<input type=number min=0 max=23 value=0 />
```

Comment: not a bad idea with the numbers, that would make it a lot more straight forward especially for the purpose of this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON.stringify() to convet the time to string.

Then use the following function

```
  var time = str.substring(0, 3);
```

This will display time in hours only

Answer (score 0):

Add `step` attribute.

```
<input type="time" name="time" id="time" step="3600"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

This will help you formatting the timepicker of chrome:
http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-date.php

So you can see, that the steps, you could choose, doesn't contain n "Hour" step.

Best solution would be an html timepicker and/or a Javascriptfunction